# Handling arrays

Tags: matrix, vector, list-manipulation

Is there a way to transform a matrix in a vector, where you choose the order of the arrangement?
I used `ArrayReshape` but this command chooses its own arrangement, for example:

```
m=Partition[Range[100],10];  
v1 = Flatten[ArrayReshape[M, {100, 1}]]
v1={1,2,3,...,10,11,....,100}
```

I don't want this arrangement. I want `v1={1,2,...,10,20,19,...,11,21,...100,99,...,91}`
The code that give me this arrangement is this

```
v1 = Flatten[ArrayReshape[Table[{m[[2 j - 1]], Reverse[m[[2 j]]]}, {j, 1, 5}], {100, 1}], 2]
```

I hope this example is clearer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80972/discussion-on-question-by-alberto-navarro-handling-arrays).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
m = Partition[Range[100], 10];
Flatten @ MapAt[Reverse, m, {2 ;; ;; 2}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
>   20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 
>   11,
>   21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
>   40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 
>   34, 33, 32, 31,
>   41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
>   60, 59, 58, 
>   57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51,
>   61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
>   80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71,
>   81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
>   88, 89, 90,
>   100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91}

Alternatively,

```
Module[{m2 = #}, m2[[2 ;;;;2]] = Reverse /@ m2[[2 ;;;;2]]; Flatten @ m2] & @ m
```

> same result

Comment: I was wondering If there was a better way, thanks!

Comment: @Coolwater, thank you for the edit and correction.

Answer (score 3):

```
Join @@ Riffle[m[[;; ;; 2]], Reverse[m[[2 ;; ;; 2]], 2]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 
>   11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 
>   34, 33, 32, 31, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 60, 59, 58, 
>   57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 
>   80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
>   88, 89, 90, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91}